# Passing header to Picasso while viewing the image using url - Android

Tags: android, picasso

I need to pass a header when I try to show a image using Picasso.

Can any one suggest how to add header to picasso while viewing the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `downloader` for that:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader

Example:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("custom-header", "custom-header-value")
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        })
        .build();

Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
        .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
        .build();
```

Keep in mind that if you are using `OkHttpClient` already, you should use that instance or create new one using `client.newBuilder()`. This way, both instances will be using the same request queue.

Comment: Work for me fine.Thanks!